# At runtime, the number of instances of a class needs to be tracked

Tags: c++, oop

> At runtime, the number of instances of a class needs to be tracked. From an object oriented standpoint, which one of the following conventions do you use to achieve this?

Choices

1. Class level variable (Static member variable)
2. Global variable
3. Constructor
4. Local variable
5. Destructor

---

Choice 1 is my choice

Am I right?

not homework.

I'm a JAVA  programmer.But I had to answer C++ quesion.

Comment: Do you want to know the number of instances in the memory at any point of time, or just the number of instances created so far without worrying about whether they exist in memory at that point?

Comment: Did your professor copy-paste some C++ homework and relabeled it as Java?

Comment: @Esko Ha, yes, good old Java destructors.

Comment: I can't think of a way to achieve this with 3, 4 and definitely not 5 as the concept of destructor doesn't exist in Java. 1 and 2 are both viable options at first thought. However I would consider 6. Denis Answer. Could well gain you extra marks if this is homework

Comment: not homework 
these're some reason:our company entrust other company testing us. we have 8 man,7 can't pass the test without 80% correct ,our company fire them without any pay.I'm the last one still alive.
I'm a JAVA  programmer.But I had to answer C++ quesion.

Comment: So this isn't a java question?! The java tag will cause your answers to be answered very incorrectly then!

Answer (score 5):

Somewhat right. Static WeakHashMap and a constructor that puts itself into the map could do the job. Every time you call size(), it checks which objects have been gc'ed.

More oop (i suppose) way is to use static factory methods, something like:

```
class Trackable {
    private static WeakHashMap<Trackable, Object> map = new WeakHashMap<>();
    private static final Object dummy = new Object();

    public static Trackable newInstance() {
        Trackable instance = new Trackable();
        map.put(instance, dummy);
        return instance;
    }

    public static int getTrackedObjectSize() {
        return map.size();
    }

    private Trackable() {}
}
```

Comment: +1 I would use `Set<Trackable> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new WeakHashMap<Trackable, Boolean>()` instead.

Comment: -1; I wouldn't bet on this working. `WeakHashMap.size()` documentation says: "Returns the number of key-value mappings in this map. This result is a snapshot, and may not reflect unprocessed entries that will be removed before next attempted access because they are no longer referenced."  As I understand it, `WeakHashMap` will only actually remove the entries when you make queries to keys, and calling `size()` won't actually trigger `WeakHashMap` to double-check which entries have expired.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: not exactly, any access operation on WeakHashMap will cause it to check for stale entries, including `size()`. What this comment probably means is that during invocation of this method some object in the map my already be garbage but not yet processed by gc. And WeakReference does not guarantee that the object has been removed from memory. So for precise tracking of objects physically removed from memory, one needs to use `PhantomReference`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by `static` members Since only one copy is maintained for the class and you can increment the same in constructor to **keep a track of number of instances created, not how many are currently available**